# How to calculate power of?

Tags: python

```
def is_power_of(number, base):
  # Base case: when number is smaller than base.
  if number < base:
    # If number is equal to 1, it's a power (base**0).
    return True

  # Recursive case: keep dividing number by base.
  return is_power_of(number/base , base)

print(is_power_of(8,2)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of(64,4)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of(70,10)) # Should be False
```

The only thing I changed was the `True` and `number/base , base`. I can't figure out how to make `True` be true for all cases except for !=1.

Comment: The answer is in your question `if number == 1: return True`

Comment: Or: `if number == 1 or number < base: return True`

Comment: Actually you should do: return number == 1; that way you will return true if it is 1 and false it not.

Comment: Rob is correct since the blank space was only in front of `return` which I didn't do a good job of explaining or showing. This works because we are using `==` which returns T/F, wow how did I not think of that.

Answer (score 3):

Since it comes down to whether `number == 1` or not, you can return that `bool` directly:

```
def is_power_of(number, base):
  # Base case: when number is smaller than base.
  if number < base:
    # If number is equal to 1, it's a power (base**0).
    return number == 1

  # Recursive case: keep dividing number by base.
  return is_power_of(number/base , base)
```

The outputs for your tests are:

```
True
True
False
```

which are expected.

Comment: This will return a `False` if `number` is less than `base` and not equals one.

Comment: @Austin Sounds like OP is considering only non-negative exponents, though if we want to consider negative ones as well then yeah this new function wouldn't work.

Comment: @Austin can you give an example where the the number is less than the base and it should return True (I'm assuming this isn't intended for bases less that one)?

Comment: Yes it is only for positives.